# Google API Places initialize map with reference id

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reference

I try to use the google api places with the getDetails() method. I only need the map with the location of a reference key from my database.
Is there a way to use the map and set the location directly with a reference key?

current code:

```
  function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
      zoom: 15
    });

    var request = {
      reference: 'CqQBkQAAAJ2ovSaBhBgD-_zyhNR-T2ZzfIKlpbvRqXRYM4K2gsbKuHuGiqIYeJ8cJDmecpxjUTM28LZ3f1XmeUQXg9jxJt_sHmDmLPiWUMP9fUYUH7yyQMzeWM9GzBqRZgUs_g6ylpLBnJffvWbqTWA3ArwSeyJoSDNG7yHlsaauOW5vFIUB34l6i3Z7mDkZ0exhcQ_tMGTudsddisZ96eoT3qZfgjkSEC4k4UTdl9VEZpoK0FFewhcaFI_IrhKbeTIiOizX6HF-SkDbO8hR'
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });


    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

the map is loading first sydney and after some miliseconds after the response from google the map is locating to the location of the reference key.

My idea is to initialize the map with the refenrence key directly without first creating the map and so on...I think my solution is not the best, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option. Use the places callback to initialize the map, provide a fallback in case that doesn't return a result:

```
  function initialize() {

    var request = {
      reference: 'CqQBkQAAAJ2ovSaBhBgD-_zyhNR-T2ZzfIKlpbvRqXRYM4K2gsbKuHuGiqIYeJ8cJDmecpxjUTM28LZ3f1XmeUQXg9jxJt_sHmDmLPiWUMP9fUYUH7yyQMzeWM9GzBqRZgUs_g6ylpLBnJffvWbqTWA3ArwSeyJoSDNG7yHlsaauOW5vFIUB34l6i3Z7mDkZ0exhcQ_tMGTudsddisZ96eoT3qZfgjkSEC4k4UTdl9VEZpoK0FFewhcaFI_IrhKbeTIiOizX6HF-SkDbO8hR'
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });


        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(17);
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      } else {
         // fall back if places request fails.
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
           zoom: 15
         });
      }          
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```